# codeception and laravel ReflectionException Class \AppBundle\Helper\Functional does not exist

Tags: laravel, codeception, laravel-5.3

I am trying to get Codeception and Laravel 5.3 to work together.

I have followed the quickstart guide at

http://codeception.com/for/laravel

I have created a sample test that checks the homepage for some text I have tried running it with

```
composer exec codecept run
```

when I run it I get

```
  [ReflectionException]                              
  Class \AppBundle\Helper\Functional does not exist
```

I have no idea where to go next with this

Comment: Update `tests/functional.suite.yml`, change `\AppBundle\Helper\Functional` to `\Helper\Functional`

Comment: Perfect that worked thanls